# Not sure how to implement bullets into Pong Game

Tags: python, pygame, pong

I want to implement bullets into my pong game in which my paddles can shoot out bullets. Right now, I just want to focus on the PlayerPaddle shooting out bullets that travel towards the right. These bullets would originate from the position of the paddle. However, I'm not sure how to approach this. I believe that making a sprite group would overcomplicate my project and I just want my bullets to be able to collide into the pong ball I have eventually. This is what I have so far.

```
class PlayerPaddle(Image):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, width, height, filename, color=(255,0,0)):

        # speed and direction have to be before super() 
        self.speed = 3
        self.direction = 0

        super().__init__(screen_size, width, height, filename, color=(255, 0, 0))

        self.rect.centerx = 40
        self.rect.centery = screen_size[1] // 2

        self.rect.height = 100 

    def update(self):

        self.rect.centery += self.direction*self.speed   # <--- use directly rect.centery 

        super().update()

        #self.rect.center = (self.centerx, self.centery) # <-- don't need it 

        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0

        if self.rect.bottom > self.screen_size[1]-1:
            self.rect.bottom = self.screen_size[1]-1


    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.direction = -1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.direction = 1      
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.turnLeft()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.turnRight()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_u:
                bullet = Bullet(screen_size, 5, 5, "naruto.png", color = (255, 0 , 0))
                bullet.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx
                bullet.rect.centery = self.rect.centery 
                bullet.draw()
                bullet.update()


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP and self.direction == -1:
                self.direction = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and self.direction == 1:
                self.direction = 0
```

and Here is my bullet class

```
class Bullet(Image):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, width, height, filename, color = (255, 0, 0)):

        super().__init__(screen_size, width, height, filename, color = (255, 0, 0))

    def update(self):

        self.rect.centery -= 3
```

Comment: use `Group()` or at least normal list to keep all bullets. Group was created for grouping elements and run `group.draw()`, `group.update()` and check collision - so it can be better choice.

Answer (score 1):

I would create `Group()` outside `PlayerPaddle()`

```
self.bullets_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

and use it as argument in `PlayerPaddle()`

```
self.player_paddle = PlayerPaddle(..., self.bullets_group)
```

This way player can easly add bullets to group

```
   elif event.key == pygame.K_u:
       bullet = Bullet(screen_size, 5, 5, "naruto.png", color = (255, 0 , 0))
       bullet.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx
       bullet.rect.centery = self.rect.centery 

       self.bullets_group.add(bullet)
```

and `mainloop` can draw and update it

```
def Update():
    self.bullets_group.update()
    self.player_paddle.update()
    self.ai_paddle.update(..., self.bullets_group)

def Render():
    self.bullets_group.draw()
    self.player_paddle.draw()
```